# Cloud Foundry setup become unresponsive after few hours

Tags: timeout, haproxy, cloud-foundry

I have a 5 node Cloud Foundry setup on Azure as part of API provisioning platform.

(3.5GB)3 nodes - Garden container

(1.5GB)1 node - Postgres

(28 GB)1 node - Rest of Cloud Foundry components like cloud controller, haproxy, gorouter, stager, auctioneer etc

```
boshuser@boshvm:~$ bosh instances --ps
Acting as user 'admin' on deployment 'single-vm-cf-on-azure' on 'bosh'

Director task 184

Task 184 done

+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+----------------------+---------------+
| Instance                                              | State   | AZ  | VM Type              | IPs           |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+----------------------+---------------+
| cell_api_z1/0 (cf0f2f38-9676-4a25-9716-67255be18006)* | running | n/a | resource_api_z1      | x.x.x.x   |
|   rep                                                 | running |     |                      |               |
|   consul_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
|   garden                                              | running |     |                      |               |
|   metron_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+----------------------+---------------+
| cell_api_z1/1 (4147fa15-98ad-4ba9-a65d-7bd3f0dfafb6)  | running | n/a | resource_api_z1      | x.x.x.x   |
|   rep                                                 | running |     |                      |               |
|   consul_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
|   garden                                              | running |     |                      |               |
|   metron_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+----------------------+---------------+
| cell_api_z1/2 (51219434-846c-4edc-a3f7-ad0b28bbc68d)  | running | n/a | resource_api_z1      | x.x.x.x   |
|   rep                                                 | running |     |                      |               |
|   consul_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
|   garden                                              | running |     |                      |               |
|   metron_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+----------------------+---------------+
| cf_z1/0 (770622e7-0fbb-407e-904a-cc69f5341cef)*       | running | n/a | resource_z1          | x.x.x.x     |
|                                                       |         |     |                      | x.x.x.x |
|   consul_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
|   nats                                                | running |     |                      |               |
|   nats_stream_forwarder                               | running |     |                      |               |
|   metron_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
|   etcd                                                | running |     |                      |               |
|   etcd_metrics_server                                 | running |     |                      |               |
|   rpc_nfsd                                            | running |     |                      |               |
|   rpc_mountd                                          | running |     |                      |               |
|   cloud_controller_ng                                 | running |     |                      |               |
|   cloud_controller_worker_local_1                     | running |     |                      |               |
|   cloud_controller_worker_local_2                     | running |     |                      |               |
|   nginx_cc                                            | running |     |                      |               |
|   cloud_controller_worker_1                           | running |     |                      |               |
|   cloud_controller_clock                              | running |     |                      |               |
|   nfs_mounter                                         | running |     |                      |               |
|   route_registrar                                     | running |     |                      |               |
|   consul_template                                     | running |     |                      |               |
|   haproxy_config                                      | running |     |                      |               |
|   haproxy                                             | running |     |                      |               |
|   doppler                                             | running |     |                      |               |
|   loggregator_trafficcontroller                       | running |     |                      |               |
|   uaa                                                 | running |     |                      |               |
|   gorouter                                            | running |     |                      |               |
|   statsd-injector                                     | running |     |                      |               |
|   syslog_drain_binder                                 | running |     |                      |               |
|   bbs                                                 | running |     |                      |               |
|   auctioneer                                          | running |     |                      |               |
|   converger                                           | running |     |                      |               |
|   stager                                              | running |     |                      |               |
|   nsync_listener                                      | running |     |                      |               |
|   nsync_bulker                                        | running |     |                      |               |
|   tps_listener                                        | running |     |                      |               |
|   tps_watcher                                         | running |     |                      |               |
|   cc_uploader                                         | running |     |                      |               |
|   ssh_proxy                                           | running |     |                      |               |
|   file_server                                         | running |     |                      |               |
|   route_emitter                                       | running |     |                      |               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+----------------------+---------------+
| postgres_z1/0 (40f5d667-81c6-4065-98e5-8e272b17ed7d)* | running | n/a | resource_postgres_z1 | x.x.x.x     |
|   postgres                                            | running |     |                      |               |
|   metron_agent                                        | running |     |                      |               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----+----------------------+---------------+
```

When I deploy the cloud foundry manifest using BOSH. It gets deployed successfully and everything works fine which it should.

The problem starts after few hours of deployment. The 'cf' commands stop responding and the apps deployed on cloud foundry do not respond when accessed from browser.

As a solution I have to recreate the cloud controller node. The setup works fine for few hours and then fail again.

Earlier the cloud controller node had 8GB RAM. I did some memory usage analysis when the setup became unresponsive. I found that on a 8GB node the memory was getting choked. So I concluded the issue might be happening because of low RAM.

As a solution I updated the cloud controller node from 8GB to 28GB and redeployed the cloud foundry manifest. The setup worked fine and I was able to access the apps from browser.

But again after few hours the 'cf' commands became unresponsive and I was not able to access apps from browser. Out of 28GB only around 8GB is getting used. So there cannot be an issue because of low memory.

Not sure why the setup becomes unresponsive after few hours.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to debug more & share the results.  When it becomes "unresponsive" check the following:  Is `bosh instances --ps` still showing your platform as up?  Check the gorouter & cloud controller access logs to make sure that the hung requests are making it to the platform.  Run the `cf` cli with `CF_TRACE=true` so you can see the HTTP request/responses.  See specifically which one hangs.  Wait for a long time (>15 mins) and see if it ever completes.